# How to optimize Firebird bulk delete with execute block

Tags: database, query-optimization, firebird, delete-row

I have Firebird table with 60 milions rows and i need delete ca. half of table.

Table rows has gps position of cars, timestamp of record and other data. Table has primary key IdVehicle+TimeStamp and one foreign key (into Vehicle table). There is no other key or index or trigger. One vehicle has 100 000 - 500 000 records.

I need delete older data, eg. from all vehicles delete data older than 1 March 2015. I tried different ways and actually use my fastest comes with `'execute block'` (use primary key). First I read for one vehicle records older then 1.3.2015. Then I am going through the individual records and prepare sql execute a block and then perform it into firebird for every 50 entries.

```
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN 
DELETE FROM RIDE_POS WHERE IdVehicle = 1547 and date = '4.5.2015 8:56:47'
DELETE FROM RIDE_POS WHERE IdVehicle = 1547 and date = '4.5.2015 8:56:59'
DELETE FROM RIDE_POS WHERE IdVehicle = 1547 and date = '4.5.2015 8:57:17'
...... a total of 50 line
END
```

Thus delete 1 million lines per 800 seconds (about 1 record for 1 ms).

**Is there another quicker way to delete records?**

Additionally, this way I can delete only a few million lines, and then I have to restart firebird, otherwise starts to slow down and jam (on the test server there is no other database / application). From early records cleared quickly and gradually takes longer and longer time.

For orientation, how quickly you erasing records routinely in large tables (not completely erase the table, but only a part of the record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found where the problem was. The main problem was that I am using the classic Winforms application (or IBExpert) and that causing jams and slowing query. I used to execute block and erases the data portions, which has solved the problem of jams, but it was slow.

**The solution was to create a simple console application and run query from it.** I left primary key and erases through it (no adding or deleting indexes) and the speed of deleting the records was some 65 per milisecond (1 million rows per 16 second).

When I tried to delete primary and add index on datetime column, than erasing speed up just little about 5-10%.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to delete **all** records older than given date, no matter the vehicle, then there is no point including the `Idvehicle` in the query, just the date is enough. Ie following should do, just straight query, no need for `execute block` either:

```
DELETE FROM RIDE_POS WHERE date < '2015-03-01'
```

Comment: yes i can, but i am seeking the fatest way for delete. If i use only date, than primary key i not in where clausule and sql query will be slow. Or may i missing something? you hitnk delete primary key before use this sql?

Comment: I expect this siple single statement to be the fastest way, but I haven't done any benchmarks.

Comment: To speed this up, the table would need to have an index on the date column (I think a descending index).

Comment: This solution i can speed up query little so I give +1, but it is not a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to delete many thousands (or millions) records do not do it in one single transaction. You better do it in several steps - delete for example 1000 records and commit, then delete other 1000 and commit - it should be faster than delete one million of records in one transaction. 1000 is not a rule, it depends on your particular situation (how large are your records, how many linked data they have via foreign keys with "on delete cascade"). Also check whether you have "on delete" triggers and maybe it is possible to temporary deactivate them.

Comment: There is no other foreign keys or index. I tried add ;auto_commit=true into my connection string and automaticaly recreate connection after  xxx deleteds, but no performance speed up. I will try other solution.

Comment: It just seemed to me that it's less jams. I can not say it clearly that this helped, but for me it's a useful information, so I give +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a combined approach would help.

1. Add (temporarily) index on date:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX IDX_RIDE_POS_date_ASC ON RIDE_POS (date)
   ```
2. Write an execute block:

   ```
   EXECUTE BLOCK
   AS
     DECLARE VARIABLE V_ID_VEHICLE INTEGER;
   BEGIN
     FOR SELECT 
       DISTINCT ID_VEHICLE
     FROM
       RIDE_POS
     INTO
       :V_ID_VEHICLE
     DO BEGIN
       DELETE FROM RIDE_POS WHERE IdVehicle = :V_ID_VEHICLE AND date < '1.3.2015'
     END
   END
   ```
3. Drop index if you don't want to have it anymore.

   ```
   DROP INDEX IDX_RIDE_POS_date_ASC'
   ```

I think that even taking into account a time that is needed for creating index, you would still save some time on deleting records.